# Django/Python - can't get environment variable using os.environ.get

Tags: python, django, linux, ubuntu, environment-variables

In my `Django` project, I need to have access to `DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT` environment variable which tells whether is it a development server or production (droplet on DigitalOcean).

I want to set `DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT` to `1` on this droplet but it doesn't work.

I've added to `/etc/environment` this line:

```
DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT="1"
```

And restarted whole Droplet.

Then, I'm trying to log this variable inside `settings.py`:

```
if os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT') == '1':
    logger.info('DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT=="1"')
    from dev_settings import *
else:
    logger.info('no DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT VAR')
    logger.info(os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT'))
    logger.info(os.environ.items())
```

Which logs this:

```
2018-03-24 13:09:43,007 - MyProject.settings - INFO - no DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT VAR
2018-03-24 13:09:43,007 - MyProject.settings - INFO - None
2018-03-24 13:09:43,014 - MyProject.settings - INFO - [('LANG', 'en_US.UTF-8'), ('SUPERVISOR_SERVER_URL', 'unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock'), ('SUPERVISOR_ENABLED', '1'), ('SUPERVISOR_PROCESS_NAME', 'daphne'), ('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'MyProject.settings'), ('SUPERVISOR_GROUP_NAME', 'daphne'), ('PATH', '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'), ('LC_ALL', 'en_US.UTF-8')]
```

But when I `ssh` to the droplet and check variable manually, it seems to be set:

```
root@MyProject-v1:~# echo $DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT 
1
root@MyProject-v1:~# su - futilestudio 
futilestudio@MyProject-v1:~$ echo $DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT 
1
futilestudio@MyProject-v1:~$
```

Don't know where is the problem, isn't it a bug?

Comment: Did you try to `print(os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT'))` just to check what it is returning and see what type of the value it is holding? Maybe it's not a `string`, but an `int`.

Comment: yes, in ssh console, it returns '1', and in django settings, it's None as you can see from log file.

Comment: Okay. Recently I passed through a similar problem. Try to access the value this way: `os.environ['DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT']`. It's the same thing, but but it solved the problem for me.

Comment: Another option to see what `os.environ` returns is activating the python shell on your droplet side and calling the variable throught the `os.environ` there and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write also

```
export DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT="1"
```

in `/etc/environment` or `.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

For working Django receives DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE enviroment variable. Pass your variable at the same way.

P.S. Configure development/productions states by passing enviroment variable is not good way, use different settings modules for different states.